# When react application is in production, while refreshing the same routes browser shows 404 error but not in localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a website where all the routes works perfectly fine in localhost but in production it works fine on navigating but not when reloading the same page, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough setting to answer especially for your case but in common the answer can help to figure out.

It strictly depends on the configuration of your server. Let's dive into details:

1. Locally there is a fallback to `index.html`, so your react application could start and get the current URL to proceed with internal routing from the react application. Typically for create-react-app or webpack-based development, we have explicitly or implicitly next configuration:

```js
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: `/somePrefix/index.html`,
    },
```

That means when your web-server cannot find an exact resource - returning of the `index.html` including JS routing.

2. For the production there is mostly another web-server, which should be properly configured to follow the nuances of SPA (single-page app) with own routing.

For instance, for Nginx can the following configuration:

```
    location ~ / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

Thats mean: try to find a resource by initial URI (works for assets like your js/css/images), if not - then return index.html.